# Incompatibility with EnhancedJumps and vimfiler?

Tags: vim

Here's the plugin I'm talking about: https://github.com/vim-scripts/EnhancedJumps

The plugin sometimes croaks when navigating backwards:

`Error detected while processing function EnhancedJumps#Jump:
line   52:
E121: Undefined variable: mappings
next: vimfiler:default`

Could it be caused by my vimfiler plugin?

Comment: Ingo Karkat, the author of Enhanced Jumps, is a member here so I suspect he will be able to shed some light on this. While you are waiting on that I would suggest you make sure you have the latest version of EnhancedJumps

Comment: I believe the one mirrored at vim-scripts is the latest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hunch is right. Because the `:redir` command cannot be nested, there can be conflicts in EnhancedJumps (which I'm the author of) if another plugin has redirection active, too. To work around that, I've added a configuration in version 3.02 to turn that off. Put the following into your `~/.vimrc`:

```
let g:EnhancedJumps_CaptureJumpMessages = 0
```

You'll lose a tiny bit of functionality (messages reported during jumping may be out of order), but can continue to use both plugins without script errors.

Comment: Thank you very much. If there's a better place to ask for help/report bugs with regards to your plugins let me know. I kind of counted on you answering here. :)